# How to trigger a flow from within a separate flow

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I am trying to use the Http Request widget within Studio to call another Studio flow, but no matter how I configure the request, I get a 401 response code. The logs also reference a Twilio 20003 error https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003, but I have tried adding an Authorization header with no luck.

How should I configure the Http Request widget to trigger a separate Studio flow? Or, if there is a better way to trigger a second flow, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work fine for the HTTP Widget in the primary Studio flow calling another Studio Flow activated by the REST API.

Widget: HTTP Request
https://**ACCOUNT_SID**:**AUTH_TOKEN**@studio.twilio.com/v1/Flows/**THE_OTHER_STUDIO_FLOW_SID**/Executions

Content Type: Form URL Encoded

**KEY:VALUES**

To:+10005001234

From:+10005005678

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks for the help.  To recap, the part I was not including was the "ACCOUNT_SID:AUTH_TOKEN" portion in the webhook.